# repeated observations average per month

Tags: r, datatable, bigdata, average, panel

I have data on households that made purchase with individual ID for every receipts under some time where weeks are code just as regular integers. 
I need to count numbers of receipts from each household during 4 weeks period.(Data is over 3 years; 1st year - 52 weeks, 2nd - 53, 3d-48). Eventually I want to have an average number of purchases per 4 weeks for every household. If the solution includes converting to months and counting monthly,that works as well. The dataset is over 100k rows. I'm quite new to R, all suggestions are very much appreciated!

```
Household<-c(1,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,1,3,3)
Week<-c(201501,201501,201501,201502,201502,201502,201502,201503,201503,201504,201504,201504)
Receipt<-c(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,121)
df<-data.frame(Household,Week,Receipt)
```

Comment: You don't mention what is an efficient solution. Keep in mind that 100k rows isn't that much. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm quite new so I didn't try much. I hope there is some quite simple solution which I am just not aware of!

Comment: The dplyr package can easily handle this request: `library(dplyr);
 df %>% group_by(Week, Household) %>% summarize(n())`  This will get you started and I suggest reading the vignette associated with the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculates the number of reciepts (rows) per houehold, per 4-week period

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

n_reciepts <- df[, .N, by = .(Household, period = floor(Week/4))]
#    Household period N
# 1:         1  50375 3
# 2:         2  50375 4
# 3:         3  50375 2
# 4:         1  50376 1
# 5:         3  50376 2
```

Then you just need to average by household over all periods

```
avg_n_reciepts <- n_reciepts[, .(avg_reciepts = mean(N)), by = Household]


#    Household avg_reciepts
# 1:         1            2
# 2:         2            4
# 3:         3            2
```

You could also do this in one step

```
df[, .N, by = .(Household, period = floor(Week/4))
   ][, .(avg_reciepts = mean(N)), by = Household]


#    Household avg_reciepts
# 1:         1            2
# 2:         2            4
# 3:         3            2
```

dplyr equivalent:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Household, period = floor(Week/4)) %>% 
  count %>% 
  group_by(Household) %>% 
  summarise(avg_reciepts = mean(n))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Household avg_reciepts
#       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1         1            2
# 2         2            4
# 3         3            2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!